# Testing fetch request to a graphql endpoint in react not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, graphql, fetch

I'm using create-react-app. I want to test fetch request to a graphql endpoint using `jest` and `msw` library.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
my-project
    src
        __mocks__
            server.js
            handlers.js
        store
            favorites
                __tests__
                    utils.test.js
                utils.js
    setupTests.js
    jestConfig.js
```

The configuration is as follows.

In `jestConfig.js` I have next code:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  }, 
  watchPlugins: ['jest-watch-typeahead/filename', 'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setupTests.js'],
};
```

In `setupTests.js` I have next code:

```
import { server } from './src/__mocks__/server';

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());
```

In `src/__mocks__/server` I have next code:

```
import { handlers } from "./handlers";

import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
export const server = setupServer(...handlers);
```

In `src/__mocks__/handlers` I have next code:

```
import {graphql} from 'msw';
import { FAVORITES_QUERY } from '../store/favorites/utils';

export const handlers = [
  graphql.query(FAVORITES_QUERY, (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
      ctx.data({
        favorites: [1],
      }),
    )
  })
]
```

Inside `src/store/favorites/utils.js` I have fetch request which I want to test.

```
export const FAVORITES_QUERY = `query Favorites{
  favorites 
}`;

export async function fetchFavorites() {
  return fetch("/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: FAVORITES_QUERY })
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((result) => {
      return result.data && result.data.favorites ? result.data.favorites : [];
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return undefined;
    });
}
```

And the actual test in `src/store/favorites/__tests__/utils.test.js` is as follows:

```
import { fetchFavorites } from '../utils';

describe('fetchFavorites', () => {
  it('should fetch favorites successfully', async () => {
    const mockFavorites = [1]
    const favorites = await fetchFavorites()
    expect(favorites).toEqual(mockFavorites)
  })
})
```

Thus in the test I have `const favorites = await fetchFavorites()` which should be intercepted with `msw` handler `graphql.query(FAVORITES_QUERY...` and return `[1]`. But the problem is that for some reason it is not intercepted and it tries to execute the real fetch request in `fetchFavorites()` and it gives me next error:

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

```
  4 |
  5 | export async function fetchFavorites() {
> 6 |   return fetch("/graphql", {
    |   ^
  7 |     method: "POST",
  8 |     headers: {
  9 |       "Content-Type": "application/json"
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I do what Lin Du suggested I get another error:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality      
Expected: [1]     
Received: undefined        
5 |   it('should fetch favorites successfully', async () => {       
6 |     const mockFavorites = [1]       
7 |     const favorites = await fetchFavorites()     
8 |     expect(favorites).toEqual(mockFavorites)
```

It still executes the real fetch and not the mocked fetch in the handlers.js

Answer (score 0):

The default value of [`testEnvironment`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) option is `node`. There is no `fetch` function in the node environment without a polyfill.

`jest.setup.js`(the `setupTests.js` file in CRA):

```js
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js']
};
```

Check if `fetch` exists:

```js
import { server } from './mocks/server';
import { fetchFavorites } from './utils'

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

describe('76303969', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const result = await fetchFavorites()
    expect(result).toEqual([1])
  })
})
```

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76303969/index.test.js (27.995 s)
  76303969
    ✓ should pass (20 ms)

  console.log
    fetch:  [Function (anonymous)]

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/76303969/index.test.js:3:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        28.263 s
```

Without the polyfill, you will get below error:

```bash
 FAIL  stackoverflow/76303969/index.test.js (13.682 s)
  76303969
    ✕ should pass (3 ms)

  ● 76303969 › should pass

    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

      1 | describe('76303969', () => {
      2 |   test('should pass', () => {
    > 3 |     console.log('fetch: ', fetch)
        |                            ^
      4 |   })
      5 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/76303969/index.test.js:3:28)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.886 s
```

node version: `v14.19.3`

package version:

```
"jest": "^26.6.3"
```

**UPDATE**

Try to specify any [absolute request URL](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node#direct-usage) in Node environment for the `fetch()` function so that `msw` can intercept the request.

```js
export const FAVORITES_QUERY = `
  query Favorites {
    favorites
  }
`;

export async function fetchFavorites() {
  return fetch("http://whatever.com", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: FAVORITES_QUERY })
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((result) => {
      return result.data && result.data.favorites ? result.data.favorites : [];
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return undefined;
    });
}
```

`mocks/handlers`:

```js
import { graphql } from 'msw';

export const handlers = [
  graphql.query('Favorites', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
      ctx.data({
        favorites: [1],
      }),
    )
  })
]
```

The argument of `graphql.query()` method is the GraphQL operation name.

Comment: I still get an error. I've update the question with the error.

Comment: @Boky Updated anwser.

Comment: What is absolute request URL when you use graphql as you backend?